# php_oAuth is not visible in phpinfo

Tags: php, oauth

I have downloaded the php_oAuth dll file from [this link](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_oauth-1.1.1-dev-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip)
and deploy in the folder ../bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/, after that I have enable php_oauth in php extension and restart the server. 
Then I execute the phpinfo file in that oAuth is not visible.

please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does function_exists('oauth_get_sbs') tell you?

Answer (score 0):

have you include the dll file and folder path into php.ini file?

If you just included the dll into /ext/ folder the php would NOT autoload it. You have to add it into **php.ini**

Comment: what is your php version? x86 or x64? make sure it is compatible with your PHP. I recommanded you get x84 it is because a lot of extension still only support x84 only. It might not work in x64

Comment: php version: 5.3.8 x86

Comment: may I know what OS[Windows/Mac/Linux] (32/64) you are using?

Comment: I found out a lot people having problem with Windows Environment. You can refer the following link to solve your problem. [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000575/looking-for-oauth-dll-for-windows-7-need-to-use-from-php-on-wamp-server) [post2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396398/oauth-dll-5-3-15-is-not-supporting)[post3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990747/why-wont-php-oauth-dll-module-work-on-windows-7)